# GKE - Private Cloud DNS addresses, how to access endpoints from office

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have the following setup:

1. GKE - Running many pods, annotated with External DNS endpoints.
2. External DNS running, creating DNS addresses in Cloud DNS.
3. Cloud DNS managed zone, with addresses automatically upserted from GKE.

I don't want to expose these dns addresses to the internet, as this is a testing cluster, but i'd like to open it to, set's say, my offices ip, address.

I'm not sure how/where to even start with this in GCP, I'm sure there's a product name for this that I'm just missing. :/

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: Cloud DNS Private Zones. To implement private zones, you need to really understand your client's OS (Windows/Linux/macOS), DNS and networking + GCP plus you will need a VPN into your VPC. Unless you really want private DNS, create a DNS hosts file and distribute this file to your users. I wrote an article on setting up Private Zones: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-private-dns-zones/

Comment: @John Hanley, it would be helpful if the comment is provided as an answer. Then it will have more visibility to the community.

Comment: @Milad - I posted as a comment as I did not think my comment was a good answer.